# Can't use ConstraintLayout! Error: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Tags: android

I want to use ConstraintLayout recently. But it seems to be more complicated than I can imagine. When I add the dependency, compile error comes as below:

```
Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
```

When I execute `gradlew assemble`, I get this:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: duplicate value for resource \u0027attr/content\u0027 with config \u0027\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"D:\\Cache\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-1\\files-1.1\\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\\b4523fa2ae32c684fd710140c71c62d6\\res\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":250,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":27058,"endColumn":68,"endOffset":27122}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: resource previously defined here.","sources":[{"file":"D:\\Cache\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-1\\files-1.1\\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\\b4523fa2ae32c684fd710140c71c62d6\\res\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":250,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":27058,"endColumn":68,"endOffset":27122}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
```

Here is my `build.gradle` file:

```
...
repositories {
    google()
}
...

dependencies {
    def app = rootProject.ext.android

    // android support
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:27.1.1"
    implementation "com.android.support:palette-v7:27.1.1"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1"
    implementation "com.android.support:percent:27.1.1"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1"
    implementation "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.1.1"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
    ...

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
}
```

I had tried to clean, rebuild, invalidate and restart. They didn't work. And I also tried to update gradle plugin. But I saw more errors. Somebody help me please! It has bothered me for a couple of days.

PS, Information you may need:

1. Windows 7
2. android studio 3.3.2
3. gradle 3.1.4
4. java 8

Comment: According to logs, it seems that there is something wrong with your values.xml file, line 250. Try to search for the error there. Maybe, deleting some lines and then readding them would help.

Comment: That file is in appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar. I am not able to edit it.

Comment: It looks like both appcompat and you (or another library) define `attr/content`. Can you search for this in your project?

Comment: They are all right until I add the dependency of ConstraintLayout. Can't I use both ConstraintLayout and appcompat at the same time?

Comment: what shall `def app = rootProject.ext.android` be good for? try version `28.0.0`.

Comment: Version 28.0.0 doesn't solve my problem